# Bootstrap carousel image resize server side

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, server-side

I need a solution that enables responsive design image resizes also the images from the server!

So for example when the user sits on a mobile, it can take quite some time to upload an original image to client at 900x900 for example.

Is there anyone who has done this before or have a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP library like phpThumb - http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

This would create images to size on the server, and keep caches for future use...

If you're running php....

**Update**

To integrate something like this in a responsive design, there's a couple ways to handle it.

1. You can use a javascript library that can detect the viewport size, and replace the img `src` attribute accordingly.
2. Use background images instead of `<img>` tags. Then you can do it natively with CSS.
3. Use CSS `:before` and `:after` and `content: ""` to insert the image tags through CSS.

Comment: and how I integrate it with Bootstrap? So I can tell the server what picture size to retrieve before I change "src" of the images? :)¨